# How to pass a List as an argument to a Fragment using Navigation Component safeargs

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data) discusses how to send simple integers and strings. For example:

```
<argument
    android:name="myIntArg"
    android:defaultValue="255"
    app:argType="integer" />
```

In the origin Fragment:

```
val action = OriginFragmentDirections.myAction(myInt)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

In the destination Fragment:

```
val receivedInt = DestinationFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments).myIntArg
```

But say instead of `myIntArg`, I wanted to send a list of integers (`myIntListArg`). How would I do that? What **`app:argType`** would I use in my argument?

Comment: Support to list of objects coming in alpha8: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111487504

Comment: What are we actually supposed to do right now to send a list of strings to another fragment and use this component :/

Comment: I wouldn't pass a list of objects to a fragment via intent though; Intent sizes are limited in size (1mb?, can't remember now). I would pass an ID or something that can allow the fragment to retrieve the corresponding data. and if you TRULY want to pass this _now_ without refactoring, you could transform your list of integers to a comma separated string and then decode on the other side (why though?), then you just pass a "string" via intent. I would not do this, but it would work fine as long as the string is smaller than the max intent size.

Comment: Disclaimer for the future readers: If your list is guaranteed to be always "short", then - when they add support to this - I wouldn't consider it bad if you pass a small number of integers in an array, but you'd have to make sure you don't abuse the mechanism in a way it's not intended, that's what I'm trying to say here. :)

Answer (score 16):

You can add array arguments like this:

```
<argument
        android:name="variableName"
        app:argType="className[]"/>
```

Note that "className" must be set like "com.google.package.ClassName".

Comment: How to receive the data?

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can pass list of integers.

```
    <argument
        android:name="yourVariableName"
        app:argType="integer[]"
        app:nullable="false"/>
```